# Python resize image and send to google vision function

Tags: python-2.7, computer-vision, google-cloud-vision

Since google vision has some [restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/supported-files) on input image size, I want to first resize input image and then use the `detect_labels()` function.

Here's their [sample code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/vision/cloud-client/detect/detect.py)

```
def detect_labels(path):
"""Detects labels in the file."""
vision_client = vision.Client()

with io.open(path, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()

image = vision_client.image(content=content)

labels = image.detect_labels()
print('Labels:')

for label in labels:
    print(label.description)
```

they use `io` to open the image file. I wonder in this way, how to resize the image **in memory** and then call `detect_labels()` ?

Comment: Does the client throw any exception when you pass it an oversize image?

Comment: Yes, it says image is too large: `google.gax.errors.RetryError: GaxError(Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient, caused by <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, Some image is too large)>)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can resize the image via PIL/Pillow and then pass it to the client:

replace

```
with io.open(path, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()
```

with

```
# Warning: untested code, may require some fiddling
import Image, StringIO

img = Image.open(path)
img.thumbnail((512, 512))
buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
img.save(buffer, "PNG")

content = buffer.getvalue()
```

Comment: Is there a way to set an upper limit on the resize operation (cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45322213/python-set-maximum-file-size-when-converting-pdf-to-jpeg-using-e-g-wand)?

Answer (score 3):

Code for python3:

Credits : @kristaps

```
import io
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open(path)
img.thumbnail((512, 512))
buffer = io.BytesIO()
img.save(buffer, "JPEG")
content = buffer.getvalue()
```