# python set maximum file size when converting (pdf) to jpeg using e.g. Wand

Tags: python, image-processing, imagemagick, wand

For subsequent processing purposes, in python I am converting a multi-page PDF (`f`) into JPEGs (`temp?.jpg`):

```
import os
from wand.image import Image as wimage

with wimage(filename=f,resolution=300) as img:
    for i in range(len(img.sequence)):
        ftemp=os.path.abspath('temp%i.jpg'%i)
        img_to_save=wimage(img.sequence[i])
        img_to_save.compression_quality = 100
        img_to_save.format='jpeg'
        img_to_save.save(filename=ftemp)
```

I am using wand because of its ability to sequence the PDF pages, but am open to PIL etc.

I need the `resolution` and `compression_quality` to be as high as possible, but I want each JPEG to be no larger than (say) 300 kb in size.

How can I set a limit to the size of the JPEG file?

On the command line I would just do (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11920384/1021819):

```
convert original.jpeg -define jpeg:extent=300kb -scale 50% output.jpg
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [wand](/questions/tagged/wand) library has `wand.image.OptionDict` for managing `-define` attributes, but unfortunately all options are locked by `wand.image.Option` frozenset. *IMHO, this renders the whole feature as unusable.*

Luckily, you can create a quick sub-class to handle this via the `wand.api`.

```py
import os
from wand.image import Image
from wand.api import library
from wand.compat import binary

class wimage(Image):
    def myDefine(self, key, value):
        """ Skip over wand.image.Image.option """
        return library.MagickSetOption(self.wand, binary(key), binary(value))


with wimage(filename=f, resolution=300) as img:
    for i in range(len(img.sequence)):
        ftemp=os.path.abspath('temp%i.jpg'%i)
        with wimage(img.sequence[i]) as img_to_save:
            img_to_save.myDefine('jpeg:extent', '300kb')
            img_to_save.compression_quality = 100
            img_to_save.format='jpeg'
            img_to_save.save(filename=ftemp)
```

*In the near future.* The `wand.image.Option` would be deprecated, and you could simply call `img_to_save.options['jpeg:extent'] = '300kb'`.